# Is the null model for binary logistic regression just the natural log function?

Tags: regression, logistic

I am currently self-studying statistics and I'm confused about the null model in binary logistic regression. I understand that the null model is used to be compared with the model you designed, but what exactly is the null model? Just ln(x)=y?

Comment: It is an intercept only model, where the only parameter is related to the proportion of '1' in the population.

Comment: Probably not just $\ln(x)=y$, unless you've defined those variables rather unusually. (And please _do_ define variables in questions.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The full model is 
$$\ln \frac {\pi}{1-\pi}=\beta_0 +\beta_1 x_1 +\beta_2 x_2+\ldots$$
where  $x_i$ is the $i$<sup>th</sup> predictor, $\beta_i$ its coefficient, & $$\pi=\Pr(Y=1)$$
where $Y$ is the response (coded 1 for "success" & 0 for "failure")

The null model, as @Michael says, contains just the intercept:
$$\ln \frac {\pi}{1-\pi}=\beta_0$$
So the intercept is the log-odds of "success", estimated without reference to any predictors.